# WEMOS D1 Mini - Cannot flash when connected to PCB

Tags: esp8266

I have a Wemos D1 Mini ESP8266 which works fine stand-alone. But when I connect it to my copper strip board circuit, I can no longer flash it. The Arduino IDE searches for the COM communication and times out.
The circuit is simple. 10k pull up resistors on D0, D1, D5, D6, D7, D8. The common end of the pull-ups are connected to the 5V pin. I have cut the tracks close to the pins to reduce stray capacitance, and tried reducing the upload baud rate. Disconnecting all the pull-up resistors solves the problem. When I reconnect them and remove the 5V feed, I am again unable to flash. It's like the 10k resistors between GPIOs (20k between any two) is preventing me from flashing the micro.
Is there a trick I need to do to enable flashing whilst connected to a circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that some outputs can't be wired to Vcc for boot.

See [this](https://www.fabriqueurs.com/wemos-d1-mini-boot-et-telechargement/) , in french (use Google translate).

[image]

Comment: Great. It seems that, in my case, one pin must be holding another one up/down during boot. Thankfully, I insert the D1 mini into headers, rather than soldered it directly. So I just need to remove it from the PCB to re-flash. At least now I understand why.  Thanks.

Comment: Great idea for headers. Good luck.